# Android Gradle: applicationIdSuffix dynamically by productFlavor

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I wanna set the `applicationIdSuffix` dynamically flavorDimension value. How can I add condition? here is my example:

```
flavorDimensions "company", "environment"


productFlavors {
    company_one {
        dimension "company"
        applicationId = "company.one"
    }
    company_two {
        dimension "company"
        applicationId = "company.two"
    }


    // ENVIRONMENTS
    prod {
        dimension "environment"
        applicationIdSuffix if (company == "company.one") "1" else "2"
    }
    // TST
    tst {
        dimension "environment"
        applicationIdSuffix '.tst'
    }
```

I wanna use `variantFilter` and tried `variant.mergedFlavor.setApplicationId` but not available. Also tried `variant.defaultConfig` but I gave `ReadOnlyProductFlavor` and I can't modify it.